# How to type diacritics?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wie schreibt man Umlaute und scharfes S auf nichtdeutschen Tastaturen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/724/wie-schreibt-man-umlaute-und-scharfes-s-auf-nichtdeutschen-tastaturen)

What do you use to type diacritics, special German characters using English keyboard?
Any hints, tips or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Try asking on [su] and explaining more about your setup, e.g. your OS and current keyboard layout. How to do this varies a lot.

Comment: There already is a question like this on main: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/724/wie-schreibt-man-umlaute-und-scharfes-s-auf-nichtdeutschen-tastaturen

Comment: Voting to close. It seems that I cannot close it as an exact duplicate of a main question, so I voted off-topic.

Comment: @thei , thanks, just saw your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Wie schreibt man Umlaute und scharfes S auf nichtdeutschen Tastaturen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/724/wie-schreibt-man-umlaute-und-scharfes-s-auf-nichtdeutschen-tastaturen)